# How to replace icon and splash in Capacitor

Tags: android, vue.js, icons, splash-screen, capacitor

I have successfully packaged the project on the device, but I want to replace the icon and splash. Is there any way to replace it?

Using Vue development, packaged to android.

Answer (score 16):

Most simplest and easiest way to do that is this package:

1. `npm install capacitor-resources`
2. Create the folder which is named **resources** under the root of your capacitor based
   project
3. Add your **icon.png (1024x1024 px)** and **splash.png (2732x2732 px)**
4. Add to your `package.json` a script definition:

   ```
   {   
       ...   
       "scripts": {
           ...
           "resources": "capacitor-resources -p android,ios" 
       } 
   }
   ```
5. `npm run resources`

Note: Make sure that you have android, ios and www folders, if you don't have "ionic build & npx cap add android & npx cap add ios".

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-resources

Comment: Works nice. Only thing I had to do was scale down the image in icon.png

Comment: Can you please specify what is the `resources` folder? is it the one that is named `android` or `ios` when built or the main folder where `package.json` located at?

Comment: `resources` folder needs to be placed as the same level as node_modules, src, dist etc

Answer (score 5):

**TO SUCCESSFULLY REPLACE ICON and SPLASH in Capacitor**

If you're using windows PC to execute your CLI. Do these 5 STEPS action

**`STEP 1`**

install capacitor resources by running *`npm install capacitor-resources -g`*

**`STEP 2`**

Create just 4 customized images (app icon, splash screen, icon background, and icon foreground) using any image editing software.

a. **app icon** -  *`(a png file with dimension 1024x1024)`* and save as *`icon.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/`* Let it replace the default

b. **splash screen** - *`(a png file with dimension 2732x2732)`* and save as *`splash.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/`* Let it replace the default

c. **icon background** - *`(a png file with dimension 432x432)`* You may decide to make the color transparent or not and save as *`icon-background.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/android/`*

b. **icon foreground** - *`(a png file with dimension 432x432)`* and save as *`icon-foreground.png`* inside *`<Project Directory>/resources/android/`* icon foreground is just same as app icon. it is the logo that will represent your app in app collections.

**STEP 3**

let capacitor help you to make the icon and splash in multiple dimensions by running

*`ionic cordova resources`*

**STEP 4**

copy the resources to the android build by running *`cordova-res --skip-config --copy`*

**STEP 5**

then run either of the following from the project directory, depending on whichever works for you. number 1 worked for me.

1. *`cd android && gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..`*
2. *`ionic cordova run android`*

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, the current supported way to do this is to use the plugin @capacitor/assets.

Just follow the instructions provided at https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to generate the icons and splash screens, along with their configuration files. Just replace the files in the desired platform and you should be good to go.
[Tool](https://apetools.webprofusion.com/#/tools/imagegorilla)

More on this, follow this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-icons-splash-screens-launch-images-to-capacitor-projects/)